# Java не докачивает url страницу

Tags: url, java, get

Cервер сайта немного тормозит.
Пытаюсь скачать с него `html`, чтобы распарсить.
В итоге получаю по пол страницы через раз.

```
    static void getHtml (String urls) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        URLConnection conn1 = url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(100000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();

        try {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String s = r.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                list.add(s);
                s = r.readLine();
            }
            r.close();
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            iOException.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то тут не чисто =)

    String s = r.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                list.add(s);
                s = r.readLine();
            }

Comment: вне методов находится(т.е. просто внутри класса)
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

но не думаю что проблема в нём, т.к. и без него всё аналогично

Comment: я так полагаю что в переменную s не успевают поступить данные и выполняется послецикловый r.close();  
как в этом случае поступить чтобы он не срабатывал раньше времени?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как ты читаешь через Reader, то у тебя нет возможности проверять оставшееся в потоке количество символов (в InputStream это делается через метод available()).

Можешь переделать через InputStream, либо читать Reader'oм при помощи метода

`int read(char[] cbuf, int offset, int length)`

пока метод не вернет -1.

Если достаточно просто костыля, чтобы проверить что-то, то воткни внутрь цикла чтения файла sleep(500), например. Таким образом у программы будет больше шансов успеть скачать html страницу.

Comment: переписал так, теперь работает отлично!
докачивает всё.   

                char ch = 0;
                while (ch != -1 && ch != '') {
                    ch = (char) r.read();
                    str.append(ch);
                    System.out.println(ch);
                }


осталось довести до идеала после тега </html> таки выполняет последнюю итерацию добавляя в конец '', редко программирую, уже забыл цикл без выполнения этой последней итерации